# How to nagivate an array based on another array in JS

Tags: javascript

Here are two arrays:

```
array1=['alex','joe','simon','sarah']
let index1= 0;
array2= [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,2,3] , [1,2] ....]
let index2= 0;
```

Initially we are in array1 in index 0, I have a next button and whenever user clicks on it index2 moves and its value become 1, then with next click it is 2 and so on and so forth.
The problem is I want to change indeex1 whenever the navigation of the first array of array 2 is finished.
What I mean is when index2 is equal to 6 the index1 should change to 1.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is `x`? can you add a table of the values of `index1` and `index2`? how are they related?

Comment: array 1 includes just some names like ['alex','joe',simon']

Comment: @NinaScholz I edited my question

Comment: Are the values in `array2[x]` always 1-K for some K or are they arbitrary values?

Comment: @jarmod they are always random values,, basically array 2 is a big array with nested arrays (random length) and each nested array includes some numbers like the example

Comment: how are array1 and array2 connected?

Comment: They are not connected!

Comment: Presumably [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] are the values associated with alex, [1,2,3] with joe, etc.

Comment: @jarmod exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example

```js
const array1 = ['alex','joe','simon','sarah']
let index1 = 0;
const array2 = [ [1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2]]
let index2= 0;

function userClick(arr){
  if (arr[index1].length > index2) {
    console.log(index1, index2);
    index2++;
  }
  else {
    index1++;
    index2 = 0;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  userClick(array2);
}
```